# Explanation of error using "color" in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In order to set the color of a batch script's console/terminal, `color` can be used. E.g. `color 70`. However, in order to reset the color of a the console, `color` without any arguments/values can be used. What is causing confusion for me is why it only works inside the command prompt or a `call`ed script but not a script started **specifically** with `cmd /c`. It fails and returns an errorcode of `1`. Is there some legacy reason for this or is it a bug in Windows?

1. `cmd /c color || echo foobar`

Output: `foobar`

Expected output:

2. `cmd /c color 70 || echo foobar`

Output:

Expected output:

3. `call color || echo foobar`

Output:

Expected output:

Comment: At startup in single command mode (i.e. `/c`), CMD doesn't call WinAPI `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` to query the console's default character attributes, which normally it sets in its private global variable `cmd!wDefaultColor`. Without querying the attached console, the default `wDefaultColor` value is 0, which causes `cmd!eColor` to immediately fail. OTOH, when you `call` the `color` command, it's using the current CMD instance, which has `wDefaultColor` set to a non-zero value to reset the console screen buffer's attributes via WinAPI `FillConsoleOutputAttribute`.

Comment: BTW, your choice of words "color of a batch script" makes little sense. A batch script has no color. The CMD instance that's executing the script *may* (or may not) be attached to a console, which *may* (or may not) have a window and an active screen buffer that can be modified by CMD's `color` command.

Answer (score 0):

To have no error, try to put the default color, as you said, 
*the color of a the console*

That means the default color, I gess, so put `color 07`, to switch to color black-light grey.

For more info for colors in a `.bat` file create a `.bat` file and put in it `color h`, only this, save it and run it. It will give you all the info about colors.

If you are not able to do this, here is what it will show you. (Sorry, it's in french, but I gess you can understand)

```
Change les couleurs par défaut du premier et de l'arrière plan de la console.

COLOR [attr]

  attr    Spécifie les attributs de couleurs de l'apparence de la console

Les attributs de couleurs sont spécifiés par DEUX chiffres hexadécimaux -- le
premier correspond à l'arrière plan, le second au premier plan. Chaque chiffre
peut prendre n'importe quelle de ces valeurs :

    0 = Noir        8 = Gris
    1 = Bleu foncé  9 = Bleu clair
    2 = Vert        A = Vert clair
    3 = Bleu-gris   B = Cyan
    4 = Marron      C = Rouge
    5 = Pourpre     D = Rose
    6 = Kaki        E = Jaune
    7 = Gris clair  F = Blanc

Si aucun argument n'est donné, cette commande restaure les couleurs
sélectionnées au moment où CMD.EXE a été ouvert. Cette valeur vient soit de la
fenêtre de la console, du commutateur en ligne de commande /T, ou de la valeur
DefaultColor du registre.
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Again, sorry that is in french

Kalolol